# Autolayout flexible width

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I have a view. Inside that view I generate many subviews, in code.  I want each sub view to stretch to the width of the enclosing view.  I tried adding constraints in code but I get a runtime exception.

```
   NSView *trackcontainer = [self trackContainerWithTrack:track];
   [self addSubview:trackcontainer];
   [trackcontainer addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint
       constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-5-[trackcontainer]-5-|"
                           options:0 metrics:nil
                             views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(trackcontainer)]];
```

The exception is:

```
2014-05-12 16:58:20.812 testApp[7597:303] Unable to install constraint on view.
Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?
That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000028e880 H:|-(5)-[BTSDoubleClickView:0x600000340fd0]
(Names: '|':BTSAlbumTracklistView:0x608000137c00 )> view:<BTSDoubleClickView: 0x600000340fd0>
```

Well, of course it's outside the view.  I want it to refer to the superview, that's why I used the pipe character.

EDIT: I just realized that I should be adding the contraints to the superview, not the subview.  I did that but now I get a different error:

```
2014-05-12 22:37:47.218 autolayouttest[29399:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x61800009e730 h=--& v=--& H:|-(10)-[NSView:0x60000013aa40]   (Names: '|':FunkyView:0x60800013aa40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009eaa0 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[NSView:0x60000013aa40]   (Names: '|':FunkyView:0x60800013aa40 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009eaa0 H:|-(NSSpace(20))-[NSView:0x60000013aa40]   (Names: '|':FunkyView:0x60800013aa40 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
```

I understand that there is a conflict, probably because I specified a width/height when creating the view's frame?  I really don't know where to go from here.  How many constraints do I need to add?  Can I remove the AutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint?  I don't have any autoresizing masks on the view (I tried setting it to 0 too just in case, no difference.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` on views when auto layout is used in lieu of AutoresizingMasks.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000014-SW157